# @import url('css/bootstrap.min.css'); is not working in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Wordpress and normally work an a Mac. I'm using Wordpress 3.8.1 and Bootstrap 3.1.1 on a local WAMP server in Windows 7. I also noticed the files are green in Windows Explorer. (in case any of that helps)

The issue I'm having is that @import of the bootstrap.css is not loading at all. I've tried putting the full path from root. I know I have the style.css file linked properly as I see the styles I made show up, but none of the Bootstrap style shows up at all in Developer Tools. I followed several guides on importing Bootstrap in to Wordpress and I followed everything they said to no avail. I'm really not sure what's going on here.

This is what is at the top of my style.css file:

```
/*
Theme Name: SSMMA Bootstrap Theme
Theme URI: http://siamstarmma.com
Description: Siam Star MMA's responsive Bootstrap 3 theme
Version: 1
Auther: CaptMinty
Author URI: http://captminty.com;
*/

@import url("css/bootstrap.css");
```

If I can't get it working, is there another way to link CSS files in wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function to added to the scope;

```
function add_require_scripts_files() {
    wp_enqueue_style('boot', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.css', array('style'), null, "all");
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_require_scripts_files' );
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but where do I add that?

Comment: `functions.php` in theme root